# SerializeArray table rows containg input and/or text. How?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, pdo

I've created a table that generates estimates. I've figured out how to add, update line item and estimate total and delete line item and estimate total.

What I am now trying to do is, once the user is done entering data in the table below, I need the user to be able to save this estimate with the estimate primary key to tbl_estimate so... I need to turn each table row into the following JSON format and then submit it to a PHP PDO page for processing.

How can I serializeArray() a table?

```js
// DESIRED JSON FORMAT

[
   {
      "PK_TP_ID":539,
      "DESCRIPTION":"LINE ITEM 1",
      "QUANTITY":"5",
      "UNIT":"SF",
      "COST":"2.24",
      "TOTAL":"11.20",
   },
   {
      "PK_TP_ID":540,
      "DESCRIPTION":"LINE ITEM 2",
      "QUANTITY":"10",
      "UNIT":"SF",
      "COST":"2.01",
      "TOTAL":"20.01"
   },
   {
      "PK_TP_ID":541,
      "DESCRIPTION":"LINE ITEM 3",
      "QUANTITY":"15",
      "UNIT":"SF",
      "COST":"2.60",
      "TOTAL":"39"
   }
]
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- Import Google Icon Font -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Import materialize.min.css v1.0.0-alpha.4 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-alpha.4/css/materialize.min.css">

<!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

<title>Estimator 1.0</title>

<style>
 
/* table_client_estimate_line_items header width
Header width = Column width --------------------------------------------- */ 
#table_client_estimate_line_items thead tr th:nth-child(1) {
width: auto;
text-align: left;
}
#table_client_estimate_line_items thead tr th:nth-child(2) {
width: auto;
text-align: left;
}
#table_client_estimate_line_items thead tr th:nth-child(3) {
width: auto;
text-align: left;
}
#table_client_estimate_line_items thead tr th:nth-child(4) {
width: auto;
text-align: left;
}
#table_client_estimate_line_items thead tr th:nth-child(5) {
width: auto;
text-align: left;
}
#table_client_estimate_line_items thead tr th:nth-child(6) {
width: auto;
text-align: center;
}
/* End Custom Table Headers---------------------------------------------- */


/* Begin table_client_estimate_line_items cell content alingment ---------------------------------- */

/* td:nth-child(1) = Table Column 1 Cells ------------------------------- */ 
#table_client_estimate_line_items tbody tr td:nth-child(1) {
text-align: left;
/* Client Name Column cells... */
padding-left: 7px !important;
}
/* td:nth-child(2) = Table Column 2 Cells ------------------------------- */ 
#table_client_estimate_line_items tbody tr td:nth-child(2) {
text-align: left;
}
/* td:nth-child(3) = Table Column 3 Cells ------------------------------- */ 
#table_client_estimate_line_items tbody tr td:nth-child(3) {
text-align: left;
}
/* td:nth-child(4) = Table Column 4 Cells ------------------------------- */ 
#table_client_estimate_line_items tbody tr td:nth-child(4) {
text-align: left;
}
/* td:nth-child(5) = Table Column 5 Cells ------------------------------- */ 
#table_client_estimate_line_items tbody tr td:nth-child(5) {
text-align: left;
}
/* td:nth-child(6) = Table Column 6 Cells ------------------------------- */ 
#table_client_estimate_line_items tbody tr td:nth-child(6) {
text-align: center;
}
/* End table_client_estimate_line_items cell content alingment ------------------------------------ */


/* table_client_estimate_line_items cell padding */
#table_client_estimate_line_items tbody tr td {
padding: 0px 5px !important;
}
/* End Custom Padding of Table Cells (td). ------------------------------ */


#estimate_total_refresh {
cursor: pointer;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>


<!-- Begin container -->
<div class="container">


<!--
888888    db    88""Yb 88     888888 
  88     dPYb   88__dP 88     88__   
  88    dP__Yb  88""Yb 88  .o 88""   
  88   dP""""Yb 88oodP 88ood8 888888 
-->


<!-- Begin row -->
<div class="row">

<!-- Begin input/column -->
<div class="col s12">

<!-- Begin table -->
<table id="table_client_estimate_line_items" class="striped col s12">

<!-- Begin table head -->
<thead>
<tr>
<th>DESCRIPTION</th>
<th>&nbsp;</th>
<th>UNIT</th>
<th>COST</th>
<th>SUBT</th>
<th>&nbsp;</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<!-- ./ End table head -->


<tfoot>
<th>&nbsp;</th>

<th>&nbsp;</th>
<th>&nbsp;</th>
<th>TOTAL</th>
<th id="estimate_total" class="red-text">$0,00</th>
<th>&nbsp;</th>
</tfoot>


<!-- Begin table body -->
<tbody>

<tr>
<td class="red-text" style="font-size: 0.85rem; font-weight: bold;">LINE ITEM 1</td>
<td><input id="" name="" value="" placeholder="" type="text" style="height: 25px;" class="red-text line_item_quantity"></td>
<td>SF</td>
<td class="line_item_cost">1.33</td>
<td class="line_item_total">0.00</td>
<td><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-flat red-text lighten-1 btn_delete_table_row"><i class="material-icons md-24">close</i></a></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="red-text" style="font-size: 0.85rem; font-weight: bold;">LINE ITEM 2</td>
<td><input id="" name="" value="" placeholder="" type="text" style="height: 25px;" class="red-text line_item_quantity"></td>
<td>SF</td>
<td class="line_item_cost">2.01</td>
<td class="line_item_total">0.00</td>
<td><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-flat red-text lighten-1 btn_delete_table_row"><i class="material-icons md-24">close</i></a></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="red-text" style="font-size: 0.85rem; font-weight: bold;">LINE ITEM 3</td>
<td><input id="" name="" value="" placeholder="" type="text" style="height: 25px;" class="red-text line_item_quantity"></td>
<td>SF</td>
<td class="line_item_cost">0.52</td>
<td class="line_item_total">0.00</td>
<td><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-flat red-text lighten-1 btn_delete_table_row"><i class="material-icons md-24">close</i></a></td>
</tr>

</tbody>
<!-- ./ End table body -->

</table>
<!-- ./ End table -->

</div>
<!-- ./ End input/column -->

</div>
<!-- ./ End row -->

</div>
<!-- ./ End container -->

<!-- 1. Import jquery.min.js v3.2.1         JS !-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- ***BEFORE*** materialize.js !-->

<!-- ***AFTER*** jquery.min.js !-->
<!-- 2. Import materialize.min.js v1.0.0-alpha.4  JS !-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-alpha.4/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<!-- BEGIN Before DOCUMENT.READY -->
<script>

// Initialization
init_1();

// begin function init_1()
function init_1 () {

// Create global timer outside keyup scope.
var timer;

// Bind keyup event to all input type=text in #table_client_estimate_line_items > tbody tr td. 
$("#table_client_estimate_line_items > tbody tr td input[type=text]").keyup(function(event) {

// reference to the inpout text we are currently in...
var self = $(this);

// line_item_quantity
line_item_quantity = $(this).val();
// Trim it..
line_item_quantity = $.trim(line_item_quantity);

// parent_line_item_cost td text...
var parent_line_item_cost = $(this).closest('tr').children('.line_item_cost').text();

// If timer has been set but user still typing...
if (timer) {
// Reset timer and abort function call.
clearTimeout(timer);
}
// Set timer to tick in 1 second for 1 second then call function and stop.
timer = setTimeout(function(event) {

// BEGIN REFRESH ESTIMATE LINE ITEM TOTAL
let parent_line_item_total = (line_item_quantity * parent_line_item_cost);

self.closest('tr').children('.line_item_total').text(parent_line_item_total.toFixed(2));
// END REFRESH ESTIMATE LINE ITEM TOTAL

// BEGIN REFRESH ESTIMATE TOTAL

// goblal var line_item_cost_sum...
var line_item_total_sum = 0;

// for each table td cell with class .line_item_total...
$('.line_item_total').each(function(){

// reference to current td text...
let td_text = $(this).text();
// SUM ONLY if td text is a number...
if(!isNaN(td_text) && td_text.length != 0) {
// if it is a number, add this number to global var line_item_total_sum.
line_item_total_sum += parseFloat(td_text);
}

});

// finally, output global var line_item_total_sum to element id #estimate_total located in table > tfoot
$('#estimate_total').empty().append('$', line_item_total_sum.toFixed(2));
console.log('Line Items Totals: $' + line_item_total_sum.toFixed(2));

// END REFRESH ESTIMATE TOTAL

}, 1000); //wait 1000 milliseconds before triggering event.
});


}
// END function init_1()


// CLICK Events --------------------------------------------------------------

// Remove line item from table_client_estimate_line_items.
$(document).on('click','a.btn_delete_table_row', function(event) {
// Deletes parent table row.
$(this).closest('tr').remove();


// Recalculate Estimate Totals..
recalculateEstimateTotal();

});


// BEGIN function recalculateEstimateTotal()
function recalculateEstimateTotal () {

// Create global timer outside keyup scope.
var timer;

// If timer has been set but user still typing...
if (timer) {
// Reset timer and abort function call.
clearTimeout(timer);
}
// Set timer to tick in 1 second for 1 second then call function and stop.
timer = setTimeout(function(event) {


// BEGIN REFRESH ESTIMATE TOTAL

// goblal var line_item_cost_sum...
var line_item_total_sum = 0;

// for each table td cell with class .line_item_total...
$('.line_item_total').each(function(){

// reference to current td text...
let td_text = $(this).text();
// SUM ONLY if td text is a number...
if(!isNaN(td_text) && td_text.length != 0) {
// if it is a number, add this number to global var line_item_total_sum.
line_item_total_sum += parseFloat(td_text);
}

});

// finally, output global var line_item_total_sum to element id #estimate_total located in table > tfoot
$('#estimate_total').empty().append('$', line_item_total_sum.toFixed(2));
console.log('Line Items Totals: $' + line_item_total_sum.toFixed(2));

// END REFRESH ESTIMATE TOTAL

}, 1000); //wait 1000 milliseconds before triggering event.
//});


}
// END function recalculateEstimateTotal()

// END Before DOCUMENT.READY -->
</script>

<!-- BEGIN DOCUMENT.READY -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

});
// END DOCUMENT.READY -->
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Fixed column widths just now. Refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[.serializeArray()](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) would only works if your table contained form elements. You only have one column with form elements.

Instead what you can do is build the JSON by [mapping](https://api.jquery.com/map/) each row to an object.

```js
$(function() {

  $('button').click(function () {
    // build json
    var json = $('#table_client_estimate_line_items tbody tr').map(function () {
      var id = null, // no idea where you got ID
        desc = $('td', this).eq(0).text(),
        qty = parseInt($('td', this).eq(1).find('input').val(), 10) || 0,
        unit = $('td', this).eq(2).text(),
        cost = parseFloat($('td', this).eq(3).text()) || 0,
        total = qty * cost;
    
      return {
        "PK_TP_ID": id,
        "DESCRIPTION": desc,
        "QUANTITY": qty,
        "UNIT": unit,
        "COST": cost,
        "TOTAL": total
      }
    }).get();

    console.log(json);
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>JSON</button>

<br><br>

<!-- Begin table -->
<table id="table_client_estimate_line_items" class="striped col s12">
  <!-- Begin table head -->
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>DESCRIPTION</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>UNIT</th>
      <th>COST</th>
      <th>SUBT</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <!-- ./ End table head -->
  <tfoot>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    <th>TOTAL</th>
    <th id="estimate_total" class="red-text">$0,00</th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
  </tfoot>
  <!-- Begin table body -->
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="red-text" style="font-size: 0.85rem; font-weight: bold;">LINE ITEM 1</td>
      <td><input id="" name="" value="5" placeholder="" type="text" style="height: 25px;" class="red-text line_item_quantity"></td>
      <td>SF</td>
      <td class="line_item_cost">1.33</td>
      <td class="line_item_total">0.00</td>
      <td><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-flat red-text lighten-1 btn_delete_table_row"><i class="material-icons md-24">close</i></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="red-text" style="font-size: 0.85rem; font-weight: bold;">LINE ITEM 2</td>
      <td><input id="" name="" value="10" placeholder="" type="text" style="height: 25px;" class="red-text line_item_quantity"></td>
      <td>SF</td>
      <td class="line_item_cost">2.01</td>
      <td class="line_item_total">0.00</td>
      <td><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-flat red-text lighten-1 btn_delete_table_row"><i class="material-icons md-24">close</i></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="red-text" style="font-size: 0.85rem; font-weight: bold;">LINE ITEM 3</td>
      <td><input id="" name="" value="15" placeholder="" type="text" style="height: 25px;" class="red-text line_item_quantity"></td>
      <td>SF</td>
      <td class="line_item_cost">0.52</td>
      <td class="line_item_total">0.00</td>
      <td><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-flat red-text lighten-1 btn_delete_table_row"><i class="material-icons md-24">close</i></a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <!-- ./ End table body -->
</table>
<!-- ./ End table -->
```

**TODO** Add [rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640404/parsefloat-rounding).

Comment: Sweet reply man! Yes! So much yes! I've kindly submitted an edit to account for TODO Add rounding. `.toFixed(2)` for a couple digits after the decimal.

Comment: May I ask, what's with the `).get();` part of your sample?

Comment: @ASPiRE The return value of `.map()` is a jQuery object, which contains an array. Using `.get()` on the result changes it into a basic array.

Comment: I see. Is it more ideal than running `Stringify()` on it? Or just another way?

Comment: @ASPiRE I don't think `JSON.stringify()` would be much use here. This solution is straightforward as you just want to convert a set of table rows into an array of objects -- perfect use case for `.map()`.