# How to convert string value to Number for exact calculation ? Javascript

Tags: javascript, floating-point, numbers, decimal

Below is the code :

```
var a ="10.9549999999999141";
console.log(a);
console.log(typeof a);
console.log(Number(a));
```

Now the above code results as below :

```
"10.9549999999999141"
"string"
10.954999999999915
```

Here See the value got rounded off from 10.9549999999999141 to 10.954999999999915, as the result of query comes in string so i want to convert the exact same value to number avoiding round off.

Can any one help ?

Comment: Relevant: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

Comment: Yes it seems to be

Comment: Javascript itself can only handle up to 16 digits. If you want to be more precise, then you would need to use a specialized library. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21278297/9038475) should be helpful for you.

Comment: probably duplicate,
check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640404/parsefloat-rounding

Comment: You maybe could try to convert to [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference). But then you need to keep track of the used exponent on your own.

Comment: There's [libraries](https://github.com/MikeMcl/decimal.js/) for this, though, using fixed-point arithmetic. `Decimal("10.9549999999999141")` will be precise.

Answer (score -2):

Sorry If I answer your question wrongly, but my answer is parseFloat(); Maybe you can hava a try!!!

Comment: Have you tried it? `parseFloat` exhibits the same behaviour as `Number`, in this case (having nothing to do with the function itself, but with the inadequacy of the float datatype).

Comment: pls use snipet to confirm your answer